# Can Magento configurable product have interdependent attributes

Tags: magento, configurable-product

Goodmorning (at least in the Netherlands),

Is it possible in Magento (1.5) to do the following;

Let's say I sell Cars. There are three options in my configurable product:

- Color
- Fuel
- Extra can of Diesel

Now it is obvious that the person choosing a red gasoline car would not have need for a extra can of diesel.. Can I enable/disable certain attributes depending on the choices made?

Is there possibly a way to use a decision system-like way to achieve this?

Regards,
Bert

Comment: If you are using Configurable products and don't create any associated Simple products that are red, gasoline cars with extra diesel the rest is automatic, the product page will do the filtering for you. This is a non-question since it is already working as designed. Have you even tried it yet?

Answer (score 0):

You can have diferent atribute sets. So that one contains color whether other contains Fuel and extra can of diesel.

However if you have colors photos for each configuration I don't recomend the use of color atribute. I prefer having diferent products with same price but diferent base image.